# totally wired house

Tags: wired

I would like to run a very efficient wired house in terms of Computers, Wifi, Printer, scanner, Samsung (Wifi) TV, DVR, Wii, XBox, Home entertainment center, recording movies, music and all the other typical home electronic devices. Are there any sites, blogs out there to get better ideas?

Editing my question. I am not much concerned about "wiring". I am looking for ideas on how different devices with IP addresses are automated, connected, used, enjoyed, optimized? For example, How can a home entertainment system be utilized that all TVs in the room connect to central "recording" system to watch recorded shows. How to centralize music that you can play from central source into every room. I am looking for ideas and solutions out there.

Answer (score 2):

There are mny sites dedicated to Home Automation. A quick Google search finds many. More and more devices are able to be controlled over Ethernet(wired or wireless) and many companies specialize in this.  In the city I am in in Canada, there are several.  They are often home entertainment resellers that have experience in the wiring and the various controls and devices.  One company that has been at this long time is X-10.  Some items now for controlling home entertaiment.  Very cost effective.  However, not as much for computer/printer/etc connectivity.

One discussion site in Canada is [DigitalHome](http://www.digitalhome.ca/forum/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any sites like that.  Perhaps you could be more specific with some questions and we might be able to help.  One thing I've always thought about doing but haven't gotten around to is wiring up my house with Ethernet going to a bunch of outlets, just like most people have phone going to all the rooms (which a lot of people don't use anymore) and have a hub for all the rooms in the basement.  To do this I'd get a crimper and a large box of probably cat6 cable and then wiring it through my walls is just a matter of visiting some home improvement sites to learn how to wire through the walls.

Do you have questions about wifi extenders or anything like that?  Personally I prefer wired connections for everything.  Its faster, you have one less frequency being shot through your body, and it is more secure (since even encrypted wireless can be broken including both WEP and WPA).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ethernet cables, check out [Ethernet Over Power](http://www.netcomm.com.au/products/ethernet-over-power). Instead of spanning cables across walls, drilling holes and such stuff... You could just carry the ethernet signal over the power outlet.

Apart from that, I don't think that hiding other types of cables is a problem...